# PayPal IPN Failing with 302 Found

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

For some reason when I run my PayPal IPN, nothing happens. I am getting an error in the error log though, the strange part is that it's a `302 Found` code, so that should be good, right?

I'm not sure why this is happening. According to what I've researched that should be fine.

The code can be found at https://gist.github.com/ConnorMcF/48a85c637ec2317d3fc3. (bottom of the middle file, I think)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your validate_ipn function, you're trying to open an HTTP connection to PayPal (on port 80):

```
$fp = fsockopen($url_parsed[host],"80",$err_num,$err_str,30);
```

The server on this port is set up to just redirect you to the HTTPS site -- hence, why you're getting a "302 Found" error.

You should probably use something like this instead:

```
$fp = fsockopen("tls://".$url_parsed[host],443,$err_num,$err_str,30);
```